# SQL Doubles confused

Tags: sql, ms-access

What does double [3,2] mean? Is it formatting?

Comment: Which dbms? (That's not ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double [3,2] means than values can be stored with up to 3 digits in total, of which 2 digits may be after the decimal.

Comment: What would I put in the format field to achieve the same in Access?

Comment: I think you can just use double in Access.

Answer (score 1):

- The maximum number of digits may be specified as the first parameter.
- The maximum number of digits to the right of the decimal point is specified in the last parameter.